# Calling a method from a nested object in an array (javascript)

Tags: javascript, game-development

EDIT: Took out the unnecessary bit

Not sure why i can't call this method - I get an error

> "textNodes[1].options.aaah" is not a function:

```js
  

  const textNodes = [{
    id: 1,
    room_id: 1,
    text: '"ZZZZzzzzZZZZZZzzzzzzzzzzZZZZZZZZZZZZZ"',

    options: [{
      text: "Wake up",
      setfadeMode: {
        fade: 2
      },
      nextText: 2,
      ahhh() {
        console.log("ahhh");
      },
    }, ],
  }, ];

  textNodes[1].options.ahhh();
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please correct the missing part so it is a [mcve]

Comment: "the index is tied to the ID"
I don't think that is true.

Comment: What is `textNodes` here? And what argument would go as `textNodeIndex`? What are you trying to perform with the code? Why do you think the index is tied to the ID? Please clarify your question.

Comment: You want to invoke `ahhh` and not `aaah`?

Comment: your example is messed up in a few ways, but it looks like `options` contains an array, so something like `textNodes[1].options[0].ahhh()` would work. But really think about whether this is an appropriate data structure - if there really should be a full array of options then why call a method on just one of them?

Comment: Make `options` an object instead, and not an array, or call your `aaah` via `textNodes[0].options[0].ahhh();`

Comment: Thanks all, Rickard solved it :D I was getting myself all muddled up. 

Basically this is a point and click adventure game (with buttons currently for navigation lol). Each textNode is a room in the game. I hope to have methods inside the rooms which activate when you enter them but now I've got this part working thanks to you guys hopefully i can figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Your intention of getting the object with `id: 1` will not work with `textNodes[1]` since `textNodes` is an array with just one element. The object in question is valid at `textNodes[0]` because of this.

Then, once you resolve this, the `textNodes[0].options.ahhh()` line will still fail because the `options` property is also an array. You want to reference the first (and only) element the same way: `textNodes[0].options[0].ahh()`. This will print `ahhh` to the console as intended.

See the result below for verification of this solution.

```js
const textNodes = [{
  id: 1,
  room_id: 1,
  text: '"ZZZZzzzzZZZZZZzzzzzzzzzzZZZZZZZZZZZZZ"',

  options: [{
    text: "Wake up",
    setfadeMode: {
      fade: 2
    },
    nextText: 2,
    ahhh() {
      console.log("ahhh");
    },
  }, ],
}, ];

textNodes[0].options[0].ahhh();
```